# Is storing Phaser Containers computationally/space efficient? (2D game framework question)

Tags: javascript, performance, rendering, game-development, phaser-framework

This question is about Phaser.js, javascript game framework for creating games, though I think the question can probably be generalised to any framework like Pygame.

Say I want to represent different in-game locations with Phaser Containers, where each container contains many images. The containers appear slightly different (contain different images) every time they are rendered. A new container needs to be rendered every 1-2 mins or so when user navigates around the game.

Is it more computationally efficient if all my possible containers are stored in a container array, and they're toggled visible and invisible when needed? Or can they cheaply be recreated and re-rendered as and when you need them? However, if it's computationally efficient, will saving containers consume lots of memory?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Performance optimization are programming-language and framework specific. Here is a nice article how you can handel objects in phaser https://blog.ourcade.co/posts/2020/phaser-3-optimization-object-pool-basic/

Comment: and here  is nice performance example from the official website, that shows what phaser can manage https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/tweens/performance-test-1

Comment: Thank you, @winner_joiner! Yes, so it seems that memory allocation for Phaser js is quite expensive and affects performance considerably, according to the first blog.

Answer (score 0):

One of the fastest ways is to store all images possible onto one single sprite sheet.
That sheet gets loaded once during the initial loading of the game, and any and all displayed things are shown by copying pixels from the sprite sheet onto a single html canvas.

If a Phaser Container is a canvas, then having too many would slow down the game.

Comment: Are you saying that each Phaser Container is 1 HTML canvas? In that case, the best solution would be to create as few containers as possible. Are you even suggesting that we reduce nesting of containers?